# jQuery array for twitter bootstrap modals?

Tags: jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a array for jQuery, so that the code below will work on all the div IDs from #myModal to #myModal40

```
jQuery(".modal-backdrop, #myModal, .close, #myModal .btn").live("click", function() {
        jQuery("#myModal iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#myModal iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Play - Video</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Introduction</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AosdkSA" height="315" width="530" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">Play - Video</a>
```

Comment: why `jQuery("#myModal iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#myModal iframe").attr("src"));` why assigning same src ?

Comment: What's your HTML? What are you trying to do? What actually happens? What have you tried so far to diagnose the issue?

Comment: I think your looking for a prefix attribute selector `$( "div[id|='myModal']" )`

Comment: @TusharGupta I found the code here on stackoverflow, so not quite sure, but it worked

Comment: @Pete I just added my HTML.

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to accomplish, which makes it extremely hard to provide you with any help. You haven't actually asked a question. You've simply posted code and implied that it doesn't work in some fashion. Please tell us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an advanced selector like so

```
$("[id^='myModal']")
```

this will target all elements with an id that starts with myModal